# Javascript not working in chrome with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2 and jQuery. I have simple HTML button as follows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="Redirect(1,'');" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
```

In the head section I have a javascript function as follows:

```
        function Redirect(id, push) {
        if (id == 1) {
            if (push == 1) {
                window.location.href('../dashjs/dashboardjs.aspx?pushchart=1');
            }
            else {
                window.location.href('../dashjs/dashboardjs.aspx');
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the function Redicect is never called in CHROME. This seems to be working in IE.

Any ideas of what might be the issue here.

The following are loaded in the head section:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../Content/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.location.href actually isn't a method.
Try:

```
window.location.href = '../dashjs/dashboardjs.aspx?pushchart=1';
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Redirect(id, push) {
        if (id == 1) {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        } else {
            window.location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com.com';
        }
        return false;


    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<button type="button" onclick= Redirect(1,''); class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>

    </body>
```

Try that. you need to assign location using =

If you want to use your syntax try window.location.replace as a redirect